# Maven dependency plugin not supported by maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

Im trying to download a Spring/Java code from a book to run their code and test it but unfortunately I get errors,

I see this is a common error but don't see a fix for my pom file,

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.apress.springrecipes</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>springintro</artifactId>
    <name>Introduction to Spring</name>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jca-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Error

```
Jul 17, 2013 3:51:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@be41ec: startup date [Wed Jul 17 15:51:20 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 17, 2013 3:51:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.apress.springrecipes.hello.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Pom file error:

```
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e.
maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.
```

Comment: Do you have a bean.xml anywhere in your application?

Comment: Yes, I have it under the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m2e is not Maven.  The POM file error is saying that Eclipse's Maven plugin (m2e) does not know what to do with the "copy-dependencies":"unpack" goal.  The way m2e works it has to understand what a goal does in a pom file so that it can duplicate that behavior in the Eclipse build.

There are a two main things you can do:

1. Tell Eclipse to ignore the goal - This will allow you to not get the error.  That unpack step will never occur during Eclipse incremental builds, it will still happen when you do full Maven builds.
2. Install a "connector" which tells Eclipse what to do when it encounters that goal.  The connector for this goal can be found [here](https://github.com/ianbrandt/m2e-maven-dependency-plugin).

As for the maven-resources-plugin I don't see any other option than upgrading the plugin version specified in the POM.  The error there is saying that Eclipse's Maven plugin can't work with Maven plugins that old.

I have no idea what is causing the file not found error but suspect it is because that file is contained in whatever it is that Eclipse is not unpacking.

Comment: I just installed Maven Integration for Eclipse but still I get the old version error

Comment: The error is not that m2e (Maven integration for Eclipse) is too old for Maven but that your plugins defined in the pom.xml file are too old for m2e.  I'm guessing that the book you are reading either did not use Eclipse or used a very old version of Eclipse.  You will need to modify the files that they are providing, starting with updating the version of the maven-resources-plugin which should be listed in the pom.xml file.

Comment: I was able to fix it after moving the beans.xml to the correct folder..Looks like it was not able to load the beans file...but still I see errors in pom.xml file...How do I know the version of the maven-resource-plugin...Should I just go and update the <version> tag of the xml file...thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

What @Pace said is totally valid, and I believe OP should try to understand what m2e is doing.  <del>Personally I hate the behavior of m2e after 0.10, for which they introduced the connector concept.  The concept is good but the way to tell Eclipse how to react to unsupported plugins is by seriously polluting the POM which looks awful to me.  Switching back to older M2E version may make your life easier though you lose some feature.</del>

Going back to your question, from the error message you quoted:

> maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.

it seems suggest to me that m2e did support maven-resources-plugin >= 2.4  (I am not sure, I haven't encountered similar issue as you before).  Try to make use of newer version (2.4 or after, latest is 2.6) of maven-resources-plugin in your POM, M2E may be able to pick up the settings for you.

i.e.

```
<project>
...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
       ....
    </pluginManagement>
      ....
  </build>
</project>
```

it is always a good practice to stamp the version of plugins you used.  This lead to a more "reproducible" build.

Comment: Later Eclipses store the plugin information outside of the POM, under .settings, so they fixed that horrible suggestion at least.

Comment: cool! I have been monitoring the progress on that but gave up a year ago :P  Glad to hear the great news